# How to use the 'overrides' folder generated by Sencha cmd for an Ext JS 6.2 project

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, overriding

What is the best practice to use overrides in extjs 6.2 application. How to make all files inside override folder require by default. In 4.2 we use to set it overrides path in sencha.config and in application requires section we used to mention overrides.*.

I tried the same with 6.2 but i failed to configure. When i mention override option one by one in application requires section it works like 'overrides.Ajax' but when try to make entire override like 'overrides.*' it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After creating override we need to build or refresh the application using sencha command. When i did sencha refresh all the override files are included by default.